# How to combine multiple SignalProducers?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

Suppose I have a bunch of `SignalProducer`s in an array:

```
[SignalProducer<Car, NSError>]
```

How do I combine them to get one `SignalProducer` that waits for all of them and gets all the `Car`s?

```
SignalProducer<[Car], NSError>
```

Use case: Do a network request to an endpoint `http://cardatabase.com/:car_id` for a bunch of car IDs and thus obtain multiple `Car` objects. The problem is that the `URLSession` function can only get a `SignalProducer` for one `Car` at a time. The question is how to combine many of them.

(Edit: Yikes, this reminds me a lot of `sequenceA` in Haskell. Can I do a similar thing in ReactiveSwift?)

Comment: You are looking for the `zip` operator in Reactive-Cocoa

Comment: @VictorSigler I don't think so because zip is for a specific number of elements, in a tuple. I have an array with a length only known at runtime.

Comment: Uhmm, yes it complicates the matter, you're right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do this using `flatten(_:)` and `reduce(_:, _:)`.

```
let firstProducer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value: 0)
let secondProducer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value: 1)
let thirdProducer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value: 2)

SignalProducer<SignalProducer<Int, NoError>, NoError>(values: [firstProducer, secondProducer, thirdProducer])
    .flatten(.merge)
    .reduce([]) { $0 + [$1] }
    .startWithValues { print($0) } //prints "[0, 1, 2]"
```